# Windows networking stops after Windows update installed KB 5021233

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking

Anybody else experience a total loss of Windows networking (not Internet connectivity) after installing updates last night/this morning? I can no longer connect to any **\servername\sharename** Windows shares, or even see them, and this seems to affect multiple machines.

AFAIK nothing changed except installation of [KB5021233](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/december-13-2022-kb5021233-os-builds-19042-2364-19043-2364-19044-2364-and-19045-2364-44e774aa-60c4-4e38-b7e7-c886d210db3b).

Answer (score 0):

Somehow all the SMB networking features got turned off.

Go to "Programs and Features", "Turn Windows features on or off", and add all the SMB features back in.  Poof, Windows networking.

Comment: SMB 1.0 is not "Windows Networking".  Do you mean "SMB Direct" or the "SMB 1.0" features we de-selected?